# Days of the week array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var birthDate = new Date(year, monthNumber/3, day);
var dayNumber = (birthDate.getDay());
var dayName = days.indexOf(dayNumber);
document.writeln ('I was born on a ' + dayName + '');{
```

Why won't this work? It is outputting -1 for me The var daynumber is right, showing the correct day number, but how can I get this to correspond/ output the actual day name?

Comment: **Should this work?** You mean you havn't tried it yourself until now ?

Comment: I have tried it and its not working for me, I've edited the question

Comment: Because `dayNumber` is already the index of `days` array. so it should be `days[dayNumber]`

Comment: What you're doing isn't working because `array.indexOf(value)` returns the index of the `value` in the `array`. The name of the method is pretty obvious if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var dayName = days[dayNumber];
```